# How to read and match web service request with ws policy enabled in wiremock standalone server?

Tags: encryption, ws-security, wiremock

I am running wiremock as a standalone server and got to the point where coming web service request is signed with binary security token and encrypted. Is there any easier solution to decrypt the request and read the contents for the request?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box WireMock does not support any kind of encryption of the message itself. Given that you may want to match your rules on some of the content of the encrypted message I think a [Custom Request Matcher](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#custom-request-matchers) is what you need.